Monitoring a Rails application with monit service when ProtectSystem=strict is used in the systemd unit file
I have been using monit to monitor my Rails application for several years. It has worked very well for me.
Currently, when I try to setup the same configuration on the latest Ubuntu LTS (24.04.1) I am facing an issue because the systemd unit file of monit uses ProtectSystem=strict which makes pretty much the entire filesystem as ReadOnly. It further has this line in the config ReadWritePaths=/run/ /var/lib/monit/ /var/log/ making only those paths ReadWrite. These restrictions are inherited by my Rails application process when started through monit.
This causes a problem with the bundler cache, which I have set to /home/ubuntu/.bundles/pw_bundle. bundler needs write access to this location. I see two options to address this :

Edit the systemd unit file for monit to allow some more directories to be writable - which I want to avoid as monit and it's unit file comes as part of the apt package installation. I prefer not to meddle with it to avoid issues during upgrades.
Use /var/log as the location of my bundle - which doesn't really sound right.

Are these the only options or am I missing something? What is the advised approach here?

Use the documented methods for extending a systemd unit: Run systemctl edit monit, or manually create /etc/systemd/system/monit.service.d/<whatever>.conf, and define your additional unit settings in that file (overriding scalar values or appending to array values; ReadWritePaths is an array):

[Service]
ReadWritePaths=/home/foo
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/bar /home/baz

…and run systemctl daemon-reload if you created the file manually.
Also consider whether it is actually a good idea to have monit spawn your application directly, given that the OS already comes with a service manager built in. It might be more useful to create a custom systemd .service for the app (as it natively has restart-on-crash, for example) and only have monit check it using systemctl --quiet is-active myapp.service.
